# How to work with MeteorJS in Truffle?

Tags: dapp-development, truffle, meteor

Truffle has not out of the box support for MeteorJS. Does this mean that meteor is not supported by Truffle? How easy is it to bring it together?

Comment: There is one approach, I've found. Better solutions?
https://robmyers.org/2016/01/26/ethereum-truffle-meteor/

Comment: There is little chance of a deeper integration between the two worlds. Truffle would have to integrate the Meteor dev lifecycle and basically becoming a Meteor extension. 
Truffle works good for having a smart contract lifecycle management, and Meteor can be best used in parallel.